# Error compiling gradle project with dependency on version 0.3.150227 google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all

Tags: java, maven, gradle, google-cloud-dataflow

I'm working on a Java app that is using Google Cloud Data flow and I'm getting errors when trying to compile using gradle.

Dependencies section in build.gradle is:

```
dependencies {
compile 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.9'
compile 'com.google.cloud.dataflow:google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all:0.3.150227'
compile 'com.google.inject.extensions:guice-multibindings:3.0'
compile 'com.google.inject:guice:3.0'
```

}

The error I'm getting is:

> Could not resolve
>   com.google.cloud.dataflow:google-cloud-dataflow-java-proto-library-all:0.3.150206.
>   Required by:
>         :telstra-targetingserver-cdf-cptmappings:0.0.1 > com.google.cloud.dataflow:google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all:0.3.150227
>
> > Could not parse POM https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/cloud/dataflow/google-cloud-dataflow-java-proto-library-all/0.3.150206/google-cloud-dataflow-java-proto-library-all-0.3.150206.pom
> >     Could not find com.google.cloud.dataflow:google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-parent:LATEST.
> >             Searched in the following locations:
> >                 file:/Users/pablocaif/.m2/repository/com/google/cloud/dataflow/google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-parent/LATEST/google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-parent-LATEST.pom
> >                 file:/Users/pablocaif/.m2/repository/com/google/cloud/dataflow/google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-parent/LATEST/google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-parent-LATEST.jar
> >                 https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/cloud/dataflow/google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-parent/LATEST/google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-parent-LATEST.pom
> >                 https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/cloud/dataflow/google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-parent/LATEST/google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-parent-LATEST.jar

LATEST appears to be missing in https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/cloud/dataflow/google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-parent/

The content at this time is:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known issue which will be resolved with the next Maven push of Cloud Dataflow which is planned for next Monday (3/23).

Comment: The issue still occurs today.

Comment: Unfortunately, that is correct. The release got delayed due to an unrelated problem. I'm hopeful it will go out late today.

Comment: This should be fixed in version 0.3.20150326 that went out earlier today.